# What is the meaning of using -g during any package installation in NPM?

Tags: npm

I know that the meaning of -g is 'global'. But if I type in the following command:

```
npm install nodemon --save -g
```

What does the -g mean in the command?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install a package globally you can use it in any of your projects, so you don't have to install it in each of your projects separately.

Answer (score 0):

Installing with '-g' option makes the package available all over your system. 
in your case 'nodemon' will be available even when you're working in another directory, or drive.